# Twitter Bootstrap - fixed width image nav items in top nav

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap site with 12 columns, logo top left, 4 main navigation items of 'span3' - all fine.

However, the designers have put 3 'important' nav items in the top right, separate from the main nav, as an image (awkward design, can't be rebuilt in HTML/CSS). This is a fixed width and requires 5 clickable items.

It requires pixel positioning - the nav items are in various positions.

I would like the image to remain right aligned on the top navigation at ever screen width. When we go down to mobile width, I would like it to drop under the logo (which is currently 'span6').

What is the best practice way to ensure the click targets line up at every screen width?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you got a jsFiddle for this?

Comment: No I'm not sure where to start...

Comment: you can use [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [bootply](http://bootply.com/)

Comment: Essentially - should I use an image map for this - or can I position <a> tags absolutely/relatively within a <div class="span6"></div> - and have the position of those links stay in the right place - or is there another approach?

I'm not sure which approach to put in jsFiddle to begin with?!